# Adding Product to Cart,Got Error Please specify the product's option(s)

Tags: configurable-product, event-observer

In magento, i have rewrite the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart` class for adding the dispatch event `checkout_cart_product_add_before`,
Due to this simple product added to the cart without problem, but while adding configurable products to the cart i got the error `Please specify the product's option(s).`

I have selected required options, even though i got this error.

when i remove `checkout_cart_product_add_before` event, this problem has been solved.
but i need `checkout_cart_product_add_before` event, how to overcome this problem.

Here is my code for adding `checkout_cart_product_add_before` event,

Config file for Rewriting "Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart",

```
<config>
    <global>
        ..
        <models>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart>Att_Membership_Model_Checkout_Cart</cart>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </models>
        ..
    </global>
</config>
```

and model class file as below,

```
class Att_Membership_Model_Checkout_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
{
    public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
    {
        $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_before', array('product' => $product));

        return parent::addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null);
    }
}
```

obeserver:

```
   public function checkLogin($observer)
   {
      if (!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
      {
         echo Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
         exit();
      }
   }
```

any solution?

thanks.

Comment: Can you show your observer method?

Comment: Evgeni, observer added

Comment: I think that the problem lies in the way you execute the redirect. Don't use echo and exit. Take a look at these articles: http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/07/21/magento-redirect-from-observer/,  http://shakyaabiral.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/magento-redirect-to-a-url-from-event-observer-model/

Comment: Even i comment the observer code i get this error

Comment: is the code simply to stop a not logged in user from adding to the cart?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake you made here.. in your code

```
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
{
    $product = $this-&gt;_getProduct($productInfo);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_before', array('product' =&gt; $product));

    return parent::addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null);
}
```

You can see there is two parameters of function :

1. $productinfo:  which contain product details eg: name, id, sku etc.
2. $requestinfo: which conatin your requested data eg: you selected options.

So mistake is here: `return parent::addProduct($productInfo, **$requestInfo=null**);`

you are passing $requestinfo as null always that's why parent model didn't get required  options value here.

I hope you under stand. you just remove "=null" from that parameter. it will definitely run.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($productInfo);` to see what exactly that array holds, Magento requires a product object as well as a quantity array, as follows:

```
//load the $product model on an ID
$product_info = array('qty'=>1);
return parrent:addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($product_info));
```

Let me know if that gives you any luck.

Comment: moose, its not work. `print_r($productInfo);` prints list of values but same error occur

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this, in your **Att_Membership_Model_Checkout_Cart**

```
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
    {
      if (!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
      {
         echo Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
         exit();
      }
      $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
      Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_before', array('product' => $product));
      return parent::addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null);
    }
}
```

And remove the observer